# eval gawk inside Perl, how to handle quotations?

Tags: perl, awk

I have a file that looks like this:

```
NameA X Y 0 Add1
NameA X Y 1 Add1
NameB X Y 1 Add1
NameB X Y 0 No
NameB X Y 1 No
```

and I'm running it through gawk as follows:

```
gawk -v OFS='\t' workdir=$workdir '{FS = OFS} {if ($0 ~ /Add1/) {print $2, $3, $4 + 1, $5"_done" >> workdir"/"$1; close($1)} else {print $2, $3, $4, $5"_done" >> workdir"/"$1; close($1)}}' input_file.txt
```

and the expected output is:

```
workdir/NameA:
NameA X Y 1 Add1
NameA X Y 2 Add1

workdir/NameB:
NameB X Y 2 Add1
NameB X Y 0 No
NameB X Y 1 No
```

That works great,

I want to now incorporate this into a workflow using perl, and have it written out in this block as:

```
else    {
    my $gawk = "gawk -v OFS='\t' workdir=$workdir '{FS = OFS} {if ($0 ~ /Add1/) {print $2, $3, $4 + 1, $5"_done" >> workdir"/"$1; close($1)} else {print $2, $3, $4, $5"_done" >> workdir"/"$1; close($1)}}' $input";
    eval {
       `$gawk`;
      };
```

where `$workdir` and `$input` are defined earlier.

I run into this error:

`String found where operator expected at xxxxx.pl line 511 near $5"_done""`

I think I'm messing up the quotes somewhere, but any input would be helpful!

Comment: Well, you have extra double quotes on the line -- after `$5"` the opening quote is closed, and the rest is syntax error.

Comment: However, there's just a lot there that might need quoting... a good tool is `String::ShellQuote` (for `bash`, if this goes through `bash`) but you may need to do more work here, to rewrite that command so that you can quote things right.  One thing that helps is using `q()` (single quotes in operator form) so that Perl passes what's inside as it is, without interpolation

Comment: Calling awk from perl can't be the right approach since perl can do anything that awk can do.

Comment: I absolutely support @EdMorton's comment  (my comments above assumed that for some reason you **must** keep your `awk` code... but that's probably just incorrect)

Answer (score 2):

Problem #1: You didn't properly construct your string literal. Specifically, `\`, `$` and `"` need to be escaped in double-quoted string literals when you wish for it to produce a string that contains those characters.

Problem #2: You didn't properly construct your shell command. Specifically, you didn't properly convert the value of `$workdir` and `$input` into shell string literals. This is [dangerous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection).

Problem #3: You are missing a `-v` in your attempt to set `$workdir`.

Fix:

```
use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $gawk_prog = <<'__END_OF_CMD__';
   ...Put nicely formatted gawk code here...
__END_OF_CMD__

my $shell_cmd = shell_quote(
   "gawk",
   -v => "OFS=\\t",
   -v => "workdir=$workdir",
   $gawk_prog,
   $input,
);

my $output = `$shell_cmd`;
die("gawk killed by signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n") if $? & 0x7F;
die("gawk exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n") if $? >> 8;
```

Note: You can use `BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }` in the program intead of using `-v` to set `OFS` to a constant value.

Note: There's no point in using `eval` since `readpipe` (the backticks) doesn't throw exceptions.

Note: Inside of single-quoted heredocs, nothing is special —not even backslash (`\`)— except for the terminating token. This makes it very convenient to generate string that consist of code.

Note: What you are asking `gawk` to do can just as easily be done in Perl.